# Changing style for a set of elements with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to change the css properties of a class when I click on an element with Javascript. My code looks like this:

**HTML**:

```html
<li class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link text-center" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-angle-left"></i>
  </a>
</li>
```

**JS**:

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("card").style.display = "none";
}
```

This should make all the elements with a class of 'card' disappear right?

Answer (score 0):

getElementsByClassName returns a collections of elements and you need to iterate over each element to set styles.